# Assign variable based on multiple conditions and multiple values

Tags: python, conditional-statements

For a certain data point, I have a max value and a min value. Based on the max and min values I need to assign a certain color. Both the max and the min value have to be in the same category to assign the color. I have tried to visualize an example in the picture below.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this in Python code? I'm trying to avoid a lot of if/else statements, but I can't find a more elegant way.

This is what I got:

```
max_value = 113
min_value = 112

color = "purple"
if 90 < max_value < 110 and 90 < min_value < 110:
    color = "green"
elif (85 < max_value < 90 and 85 < min_value < 90) or (110 < max_value < 115 and 110 < min_value < 115):
    color = "orange"
elif (max_value < 85 and min_value < 85) or (max_value > 115 and min_value > 115):
    color = "red"

print(color)
```

[image]

Comment: This seems more like a code review question.

Comment: if you will treat red regions and orange regions as separated object then you will have very simiarl `if/elif` which you could write with dictionary/list  and `for`-loop

Answer (score 0):

You can describe your color range and check against your min and max value (in one line!)

```py
import math

COLOR_RANGES = (
    ('orange', ((85, 90), (110, 115))),
    ('green', ((90, 110),)),
    ('red', ((-math.inf, 85), (115, math.inf))),
    ('purple', None),  # base case, when none of the previous ones is matched; you must put it always at the end of this tuple
)

color = next(filter(lambda x: x[1] is None or any(b < min_value <= max_value < e for b, e in x[1]), COLOR_RANGES))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will treat every `red region` and `orange region` as separted object then you can write it as
(I borrow `math.inf` from @PieCot answer)

```
if 90 < max_value < 110 and 90 < min_value < 110:
    color = "green"

elif 85 < max_value < 90 and 85 < min_value < 90:
    color = "orange"

elif 110 < max_value < 115 and 110 < min_value < 115:
    color = "orange"

elif -math.inf < max_value < 85 and -math.inf < min_value < 85:
    color = "red"

elif 115 < max_value < math.inf and 115 < min_value < math.inf:
    color = "red"
```

and then all `if/else` are similar and you can keep them as list

```
ranges = [
    (-math.inf, 85, 'red'), 
    (85, 90, 'orange'),
    (90, 100, 'green'),
    (110, 115, 'orange'),
    (115, math.inf, 'red'),
]
```

and then you can use it with `for`-loop

```
ranges = [
    (-math.inf, 85, 'red'), 
    (85, 90, 'orange'),
    (90, 100, 'green'),
    (110, 115, 'orange'),
    (115, math.inf, 'red'),
]

color = "purple"

for low, high, new_color in ranges:
    if low < min_value < high and low < max_value < high:
        color = new_color
        break
        
print(color)
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same using `None` instead of `math` needs different comparitions to make it simple

```
ranges = [
    (None, 85, 'red'),
    (85, 90, 'orange'),
    (90, 100, 'green'),
    (110, 115, 'orange'),
    (115, None, 'red'),
]

color = "purple"

for low, high, new_color in ranges:
    if (low is not None) and not (low < min_value and low < max_value):
        continue

    if (high is not None) and not (min_value < high and max_value < high):
        continue

    color = new_color
    break

print(color)
```

Or it would need

```
color = "purple"

for low, high, new_color in ranges:
    if (high is None) and (low < min_value and low < max_value):
        color = new_color
        break

    if (low is None) and (min_value < high and max_value < high):
        color = new_color
        break

    if low < min_value < high and lowe < max_value < high:
        color = new_color
        break
```

It has to be `low is not None` instead of `not low` and `low is None` instead of `low` because for `low = 0` (zero) it would give wrong result. `bool(0)` and `bool(None)` gives `False`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the bisect module to map values to range indexes:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
breaks = [85,90,110,115]
colors = ["Red","Orange","Green","Orange","Red"]

min_value = 112
max_value = 113

minColor = colors[bisect_left(breaks,min_value)]
maxColor = colors[bisect_left(breaks,max_value)]    
color    = minColor if minColor == maxColor else "Purple"

print(color) # Orange
```

Or, you could convert the distance from center (100) into indexes by chunks of 5:

```
colors   = ["Green"]*2+["Orange","Red"]

minColor = colors[min(3,abs(min_value-100)//5)]
maxColor = colors[min(3,abs(max_value-100)//5)]
color    = minColor if minColor == maxColor else "Purple"

print(color) # Orange
```

Or you could use the next function to find the first value/color tuple in a list:

```
colors = [("Red",85),("Orange",90),("Green",110),("Orange",115)]

minColor = next((c for c,b in colors if min_value < b),"Red")
maxColor = next((c for c,b in colors if max_value < b),"Red")
color    = minColor if minColor == maxColor else "Purple"

print(color) # Orange
```